# jQuery: Is there a tag like change() that also runs on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a set of radio buttons that triggers a jquery function if a specific value is chosen (via .change())

However, in some cases that value will be chosen by default when the page loads. At the moment I have two separate functions - one inside the .change() event, and a conditional that runs on pageload. I'd like to clean this up, so: is there an event which runs both when a value is changed, and at pageload?

Cheers...

Comment: You can just trigger the `change` event on page load.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) your `change` event on pageload like this -

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#myradioButton").trigger('change');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can use the same handler.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    radioChangeHandler(); // Call it when the DOM is ready
    $('...').change(radioChangeHandler); // Attach it to the radio buttons
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send the deselect the default value on the server (or on client-side), and after binding the change handler, you can call:

```
   $('#radio').change();
```

In other words, the whole process is:

```
 $(function(){
     // deselect the default value
     $('#radio').removeAttr('checked');
     // binding radios
     $('#radios').change(function(){});
     // Changing the value of the default radio
     $('#radio').attr('checked', 'checked');
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

The normal approach would be to make the call in a separate function, and call this from both places. There is nothing that you can call as you seem to want to.

Yes it does feel slightly untidy to have the same calls in two places, but they have different approaches. The change method is reacting to a control event, whereas the pageload is responding to a page being loaded ( duh ).

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like `$(".radio").triggerHandler("change")` on page load to trigger event handler without changing state.